# Change date directories with old date in a batch

Tags: linux, bash, directory, touch

I recently sorted a bunch of files into directories by subject.  I'm trying to change the date of the directory to be the same as the modification time of the newest file in the directory.  I have a script that I think *should* work, but it doesn't.

```
for DIRECTORY in * ; do FILE=`ls -1 --sort=time "$DIRECTORY" | tail -n 1` ; DATE=`stat -c %y "$DIRECTORY/$FILE" | tr '.' ' ' | awk '{print $1,$2}' ` ; echo $DATE $DIRECTORY ; touch -m -d "$DATE" "$DIRECTORY" ; done
```

It seems like it should work, but it doesn't.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Simply run this command :

```
latestFile=$(ls -1t | sed q)
for i in *; do touch -r "$latestFile"; done
```

! The command is not compatible with files with spaces !